# Consolidate Rows with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, consolidation

Trying to consolidate test results so that each test is in one row. Database I am pulling from has an answer result per row. Sample Data:

| Student Name | Test Name | Question Attempt | Answered Correctly (0 = no, 1= yes) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mary | Intro Assessment | 1 | 1 |
| Mary | Intro Assessment | 1 | 0 |
| Mary | Intro Assessment | 1 | 1 |
| Joseph | Intro Assessment | 1 | 1 |
| Joseph | Intro Assessment | 1 | 1 |
| Joseph | Intro Assessment | 1 | 1 |
| Tom | Intro Assessment | 1 | 0 |
| Tom | Intro Assessment | 1 | 0 |
| Tom | Intro Assessment | 1 | 1 |

Desired result if possible:

| Student Name | Test Name | Question Attempt | Answered Correctly |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mary | Intro Assessment | 3 | 2 |
| Joseph | Intro Assessment | 3 | 3 |
| Tom | Intro Assessment | 3 | 1 |

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you just want a basic `GROUP BY` with some `SUM`s:

```
SELECT "Student Name", "Test Name"
    , SUM("Question Attempt") "Question Attempt"
    , SUM("Answered Correctly") "Answered Correctly"
FROM mytable
GROUP BY "Student Name", "Test Name"
```

`GROUP BY "Student Name", "Test Name"` means you want one row per unique student/test and `SUM` explains how you want the other data combined.

Answer (score 2):

```
select student_name, test_name
    , count(question_attempt), sum(answered_correctly) 
from table
group by student_name, test_name
```